# Problem installing 12.04 to dual-boot with 13.10

Tags: 12.04, 13.10, system-installation

I have a system currently with Ubuntu 13.10, setup to boot to commandline.

We want to also have Ubuntu 12.04 installed as dual-boot.
I downloaded the ISO, burned to USB and tried installing. But the installation GUI won't start, see picture attached. The system isn't hang, you can still type on the commandline but it doesn't do anything.

[image: the image]

I tried using 13.10 ISO and followed the same steps and was able to get to the install-GUI without issue.

Any idea?

Comment: How did you create the USB? Try using a different tool for that.

Comment: @terdon I tried Rufus and LinuxLive. It worked with 13.10 ISO tho so shouldn't be an issue with ISO burning software. I also downloaded the 12.04 ISO twice and failed both times.

Comment: It can actually be an issue. Different Linux versions use different default setups. I've had distros that install fine with USBs created with `unetbootin` fail on USBs created with `multisystem` and vice versa. Same distribution mind you, just different versions of it.

Comment: Arh I'd guess both current Ubuntu versions would behave the same... anyway I'll try other ISO-USB tools and see. Did my screencap provide any useful info wrt what's happening tho?

Comment: Looks like the issue is with 12.04.**4** but not with 12.04.

For 64bits, the current link (from ubuntu Desktop) says 12.04LTS but it's actually 12.04.4, which is the one failing from my original question.

I went to the Chinese version link (Ubuntu 桌面版) which gives you actual 12.04LTS (instead of 12.04.4)... and now the installation GUI loads up no problem.